# How do I make an image move in ruby/shoes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, animation

I am currently programming a "Pacman"-game. Now I want to my ghost to move from left to right. I just can't figure it out ...
I tried moving a regular circle and it funktions! But as soon as I want to move my image it won't work.Is there any way I can fix this problem? Or can't images be animated in this way?

```
Shoes.app width: 900, height:600 do

  flow width: 0.9, height: 0.9 do
    stack width: 0.8, height: 1.0 do
    end
    background black

#field
  fill blue
  rect(270, 0, 60, 60)
  rect(0, 290, 60, 60)
  rect(540, 290, 60,60)
  rect(270,420 , 60, 60)
  rect(290, 100, 20, 50)
  rect(180, 100, 240, 20)
  rect(290, 240, 20, 50)
  rect(180, 270, 240, 20)
  rect(290, 340, 20, 30)
  rect(130, 180, 50, 30)
  rect(420, 180, 50, 30)
  rect(220, 340, 160, 10)

  stroke white

  line(50,50,100,50)
  line(50, 50, 50, 100)
  line(500, 50, 550, 50)
  line(550, 50, 550, 100)
  line(150, 50, 210, 50)
  line(150, 50, 150, 70)
  line(390,50 ,450, 50)
  line(450, 50, 450, 70)
  line(100, 100, 100, 160)
  line(100, 160, 80, 160)
  line(0, 200, 50, 200)
  line(100, 200, 80, 200)
  line(100, 200, 100, 260)
  line(500, 150, 500, 250)
  line(550, 200, 600, 200)
  line(500, 150, 520, 150)
  line(500, 250, 520, 250)
  line(240, 180, 240, 220)
  line(360, 180, 360, 220)
  line(50, 380, 50, 430)
  line(50, 430, 100, 430)
  line(110, 320, 110, 380)
  line(80, 380, 140, 380)
  line(190, 400, 190, 440)
  line(180, 400, 190, 400)
  line(420, 400, 420, 440)
  line(420, 400, 430, 400)
  line(480, 430, 540, 430)
  line(540, 380, 540, 430)
  line(460, 320, 460, 370)
  line(420, 370, 490, 370)

  #images
  @image1 = image"pacman.png", height: 25, width: 25, left:290, top: 180
  @image2 = image"bomb.png", height: 30, width: 30, left:200, top:300
    @image3 = image"bomb.png", height: 30, width: 30
    @image4 = image"bomb.png", height: 30, width: 30
    @image5 = image"bomb.png", height: 30, width: 30
  @image6 = image"pizza-slice.png", height: 30, width: 30, left:300, 
top:300

   #bombs
    @timer1= timer(5) do
      @image2.move(60,70)
      @image3.move(150,300)
      @image4.move(400,230)
      @image5.move(500,380)
    end

     @image2= timer(15) do
      @image2.move(60,170)
      @image3.move(80,300)
      @image4.move(230,230)
      @image5.move(500,300)
    end

    @image3= timer(25) do
      @image2.move(470,50)
      @image3.move(510,190)
      @image4.move(20,400)
      @image5.move(100,50)
    end

   #moving ghost
   speed = 1
   x = 150
   y = 10
   dir   = 1    
ghost = image"ghost.png", height: 30, width:30, left:170, top:60

   @moving_ghost = animate (60) do
      y =  y + speed*dir
    ghost.move(x, y)
      if image.left >= height() or image.left <= 0 then
         dir = -dir 
      end
end


#showing score
   stack width: 0.2, height: 0.15 do
   background burlywood
     @image8 = image"chronometer.png", height: 30, width: 30, left: 30, 
top: 5
     @image9 = image"score.png", height: 30, width: 30, left: 100, top: 0
   end
end
```